# What is the best way to use the AWS CDK to get the CIDR of the VPC?

Tags: aws-cdk

I've started using the AWS CDK to stand up a new VPC, but I am struggling when trying to query other existing VPCs and their CIDR ranges - this is to ensure that my new VPC does not overlap with existing CIDR ranges. The return string is not something I can understand. Could you provide an example on how to query for a list of CIDR ranges in subnets?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you trying to query VPCs that are already installed on your account?

Comment: Yes, exactly as I described.

Comment: "The return string is not something I can understand." -> can you tell me the command you've been running and the output? Are you using the AWS CLI to get the list of VPCs?

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to reference an existing VPC into your CDK stack, you should use the [`VpcNetwork.import`](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/refs/_aws-cdk_aws-ec2.html?highlight=vpcnetworkref#@aws-cdk/aws-ec2.VpcNetworkRef.import) static method which doesn't require you to specify the CIDR blocks of the VPC.

You will need other information specified in [`VpcNetworkRefProps`](https://awslabs.github.io/aws-cdk/refs/_aws-cdk_aws-ec2.html?highlight=vpcnetworkref#@aws-cdk/aws-ec2.VpcNetworkRefProps), which shouldn't be too hard to obtain from the AWS Console or the AWS CLI:

Something like:

```
const externalVpc = VpcNetwork.import(this, 'ExternalVpc', {
  vpcId: 'vpc-bd5656d4',
  availabilityZones: [ 'us-east1a', 'us-east-1b' ],
  publicSubnetIds: [ 'subnet-1111aaaa', 'subnet-2222bbbb' ],
  privateSubnetIds: [ 'subnet-8368fbce', 'subnet-8368abcc' ],
});
```

We are looking at making this easier (see [#506](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-cdk/issues/506))